# How to get the VPN icon in Kali 2.0 (gnome) as root?

Tags: virtualbox, kali-linux, vpn, openvpn

I have trouble getting the VPN status icon into the top bar for Kali 2.0 (gnome).

### Installation

I recently installed latest kali 2.0 (in a VirtualBox from `kali-linux-2.0-amd64.iso`).
I checked the `sources.list` to contain both: http://http.kali.org/kali and http://security.kali.org/kali-security.

I mostly followed the guide to install vpn for kali from http://www.blackmoreops.com/2015/03/01/setup-vpn-on-kali-linux/ with one exception: packager `network-manager-strongswan` doesn't seem to exist (which is weird since it existed 1-2 days ago). I additionally installed `strongswan-nm`.

After a reboot I could add a new openvpn connection from a file (opvn) and start it. I got connected.
Immediately after this I could see the VPN submenu with Wire-with-a-lock icon in the drop down menu (nothing in the Top Bar) still stating "Off" while I was successfully connected.

I disconnected vpn.

### The Problem

- After rebooting I don't see the menu for VPN anymore in the drop down menu in the upper right
- When successfully starting a vpn connection (from opening the network menu, selecting vpn and hitting the start button), there's no indication like a vpn icon in the Top Bar, so you never really know if the connection is active or not.

Any solutions?

**Update:** Looks like the problem is somehow related to the root user. If I login as a non-root user, I get the icon and functionality working.

Since I'd like to run kali as root (less problems with wireshark etc.) I still like to get the icon and vpn working correctly, so the **the question is still open**.